# How to retrieve system object code or definition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Hi i am using SQL Server 2012. i would like to view the system objects code/definition. can we view the system objects definition/code in SQL Server any version ?
wanted to know when i execute this query SELECT MONTH(18/200), MONTH(200/18) i am getting output 1 for both just want to know internal code what is going on and how it is giving output 1 for MONTH(200/18) ? to understand this looking for MONTH() function code.

Comment: Which system objects?

Comment: lets says there is inbuild function name MONTH() i would like to view its code. can it be possible ?

Comment: No. Why would the code be available? That code is part of the SQL Server database engine.

Comment: i would like to use its functionality/ part of code in to User Defined object

Comment: And what problem do you have when you try to use it?

Comment: i am working on DMV where collecting different types of statistics on particular DB Server now i have to collect statistics return by sp_spaceused so would like to modify the code and it should give me stats for particular DB whenvere i execute it.

Comment: What does that have to do with `MONTH`?

Comment: got the answer here it is exec sp_helptext 'sp_spaceused' by this i am able to view its code.

Comment: i thought it will great if i can able to know when i execute this query SELECT MONTH(18/200), MONTH(200/18) i am getting output 1 for both just want to know internal code what is going on and how it is giving output 1 for MONTH(200/18) ?

Comment: Reading the documentation works pretty well. And ask yourself "what is the value of `18/200` and `200/18`? Then, what kind of value does `MONTH` take as a parameter?

Comment: any integer to the MONTH() interprets 0 as January 1, 1900. that's whey it is returning 1 1 as output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

answer to SELECT MONTH(18/200), MONTH(200/18) is any integer to the MONTH() interprets 0 as January 1, 1900. that's whey it is returning 1 1 as output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

> An information schema view is one of several methods SQL Server
> provides for obtaining metadata.
>
> Information schema views provide an
> internal, system table-independent view of the SQL Server metadata.
>
> Information schema views enable applications to work correctly
> although significant changes have been made to the underlying system
> tables.
>
> The information schema views included in SQL Server comply
> with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: actually i am looking for lets says there is inbuild function name MONTH() i would like to view its code.